# Create event google calendar from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I’m trying to create a event in my google calendar from a cell on a spreadsheet. This is what I have so far, but is not working. Any ideas?

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
let XCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendaiID");
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

let task = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
task.splice(0.1);

task.forEach(function(entry){
XCalendar.createAllDayEvent(entry[0],entry[1])
})
}
```

This is how the sheet looks.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP9An.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendaiID");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  let vs = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    cal.createAllDayEvent(r[0], new Date(r[1]))
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that B2 and B3 have Date values and not Text values, replace `task.splice(0.1);` by `task.splice(0, 1);` (comma instead of dot) or by `task.shift();` (I prefer the last)

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  let XCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendaiID");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  let task = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  task.shift();

  task.forEach(function(entry){
    XCalendar.createAllDayEvent(entry[0],entry[1])
  })
}
```

Comment: Solved! It was just the comma. Can’t believe it hahah